# How to specify source location in azcopy for a folder under root of my website

Tags: azure, azcopy

I have a website on azure. Let's say the website url on azure is `https://example.com`
There is a folder under root i.e. `~/imgs` for this website to store images uploaded by users.

Can I use `https://example.com/imgs`  instead of `C:\myDirectory` in command below?

I looked up the docs for azcopy v10 online (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-blobs), but could not find any example where source location is specified using a web url.

```
azcopy copy 'C:\myDirectory' 'https://mystorageaccount.dfs.core.windows.net/mycontainer' --recursive
```

Comment: So basically what you want to do is copy all files stored under `imgs` folder in your website to Azure Storage using azcopy. Right?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I use https://example.com/imgs instead of C:\myDirectory in
>   command below?

Simple answer is No. `azcopy` utility does not have support for enumerating contents of a folder on a remote web server.

Comment: Ok. Then, how would one copy an azure website folder to azure blob account? May be I can run the same azcopy command in azure cli using the local path on azure webserver for the imgs folder. Then it would comply with the file path being used for source location.

Comment: You mentioned that you use this imgs folder on your website to store content uploaded by your users. Why don't you save that content directly in Azure Storage to begin with?

Comment: Actually, we are trying to do just that, but we need to first migrate existing images to blobs and then change existing uploading code so it writes to azure blob rather than to the file system. We already have thousands of files in imgs folder.

Comment: Aah, I see. You could in that case connect to your web server using FTP, download the files locally and upload them in blob storage using azcopy.

Comment: Ok. How about using azure storage explorer? It's a graphical user interface to upload a file or directory to blob storage. I think it uses azcopy internally.

Comment: Sure. You can use Azure Storage Explorer to upload the files in Azure Storage from your local computer.